# req.getValidationErrors() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, express

I'm trying to use `express-validator` to validate a basic contact form and I keep getting an error that says:

```
TypeError: req.getValidationErrors() is not a function
```

Here is a shortened version of my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var validator = require('express-validator');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(validator());

app.post('/send-message', function(req, res) {
    req.checkBody('name', 'Empty name field').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Empty email field').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email', 'Invalid email format').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('message', 'Empty message field').notEmpty();

    req.getValidationErrors().then(function(errors) {
        if (errors) {
            res.json({ message: 'Failed' });
        }

        res.json({ message: 'Success' });
    });
});
```

Everything works until I try to call `getValidationErrors()` on the `req` object.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You sure `express-validator` is imported successfuly?

Comment: The code seems ok, did you install the packages?

Comment: Hi, maintainer of express-validator here.  
I'm sorry for this problem. This is new API, unreleased for now, planned for an upcoming v3.0.0.

For now, check the docs at npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own question...

`req.getValidationErrors()` just isn't a function. So the code example in the documentation was not up-to-date I suppose.

This turns out to be the correct usage:

```
var errors = req.validationErrors();

if (errors) {
    res.json({ errors: errors });
}

res.json({ message: 'Success' });
```